# Dynamically Obtain DHCP info From Cradlepoint Router

Tags: php, ssh, dhcp

I'm hoping this isn't too specific, but I'm attempting to pull the DHCP record off a cradlepoint router.  Utilizing SSH to get into the router I can run 'get /status/dhcpd/' and get a JSON return of all the DHCP lease info.

I have no idea how to either a) write that output to a file or b) get that output as a variable to parse.

The ideal situation would be to have a php script that could SSH in and pull this info then write it to a file.  I'm not familiar with PHP SSH libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Incase anyone else is looking for an answer to this:

CradlePoint has a developer API.  It took me forever to find, but you can get a json output from an API url.  This is every configuration set on the cradlepoint.

If you go to http://cp/api/status/dhcpd/leases you can see all the DHCP info for every machine connected.  Utilizing a simple cURL script you can access this by passing the login credentials and returning it as a JSON array.

I spent nearly a month looking for a solution to this, and the same day I post to StackOverflow looking for help I found the API, which can be found here:

http://dev.cradlepoint.com/doku.php?id=conventions

Answer (score 2):

You can do SSH with phpseclib. eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Link: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/index.html